# tkinter, и функция с while True

Tags: python, tkinter, while

Использую tkinter, при нажатии на кнопку в вызванмом меню, запускается функция в которой есть while True, из-за чего пока функция работает я не могу использовать меню в tkinter, могу ли я запускать и останавливать функцию через tkinter, чтобы меню и функция помогли работать по отдельности :

Пример - нажал на кнопку on запустилась функция, меню продолжает работать и функция тоже, при нажатии кнопки off выключается функция а меню остаётся.

Был бы очень рад если поможете

Comment: Здесь вам поможет многопоточное или асинхронное программирование

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить вам несколько вариантов решения:

1. Использовать метод .after()

   ```
   def loop():
       root.after(10, loop) # где 10 это время через которое будет вызвана функция loop в мс
       # Ваш код
   loop() # Функцию достаточно вызвать лишь единожды после чего она будет выполняться постоянно
   ```
2. Использовать потоки

   ```
   from threading import Thread

   def loop():
       while True:
          # Ваш код
   new_thread = Thread(target=loop)  # Создаём поток
   new_thread.start()  # Запускаем поток
   ```
3. Использовать асинхронность. Ответы уже были даны и описаны максимально обширно вот тут: [Use asyncio and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui)